# Why does my code say "Yes" when it should say "No"?

Tags: c++, class, boolean

When putting freeSeats to 0, my code still says that a person has avalibale seats in his/hers car.

I have created two classes. One for Car and one for Person. The Car class has a function to see if there are free seats in the car. A person-object can have a car. When checking if the person has avalibale seats, my code responds "Yes" even though I give input "0". Why?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

//Here is class Car declaration
class Car {
private:
    unsigned int freeSeats; 
public:
    bool hasFreeSeats() const; 
    void reserveFreeSeat();
    Car( unsigned int freeSeats);

};


//Here is function definition
#include "Car.h"

bool Car::hasFreeSeats() const {
    if (freeSeats > 0)
        return true; 
    return false;
}

void Car::reserveFreeSeat() { 
    --freeSeats; 
}

Car::Car(unsigned int freeSeas) : 
    freeSeats{ freeSeats }        
{
}


//Here is class Person declaration

class Person {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string email; 
    Car *car; //pointer to a car
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string email, Car *car = nullptr);
    std::string getName() const; 
    std::string getEmail() const; 
    void setEmail(); 
    bool hasAvalibaleSeats() const; 
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Person& p);
};

//Here is function definition 


Person::Person(std::string name, std::string email, Car *car) : 
    name{ name }, email{ email }, car{ car }
{
}

std::string Person::getName() const {
    return name;
}

std::string Person::getEmail() const {
    return email;
}

void Person::setEmail() {
    std::string newEmail;
    std::cout << "What is the e-mail adress?";
    std::cin >> newEmail;
    email = newEmail;
    std::cout << "E-mail has been set." << std::endl;
}


bool Person::hasAvalibaleSeats() const {
    if (car != nullptr) { //check if there is a car
        return car->hasFreeSeats(); 
    }
    return false; 
}



std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
    std::string seats = "No";
    if (p.hasAvalibaleSeats())
        seats = "Yes";
    return os << "Name: " << p.name << "\nE-mail: " << p.email << "\nHas free seats: " << seats << std::endl;
}

//From main im calling
#include "Car.h"
#include "Person.h"

int main() {
    Car ferrari{ 2 };
    Car bugatti{ 3 };
    Car jeep{0};


    Person one{ "Aleksander","aleks@aleks.com", &ferrari };
    Person two{ "Sara","sara@sara.com", &bugatti };
    Person three{ "Daniel", "daniel@daniel.com", &jeep };
    Person four{ "Chris", "chris@chris.com" };

    std::cout << one << std::endl;
    std::cout << two << std::endl;
    std::cout << three << std::endl;
    std::cout << four << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get

Name: Aleksander
E-mail: aleks@aleks.com
Has free seats: Yes

Name: Sara
E-mail: sara@sara.com
Has free seats: Yes

Name: Daniel
E-mail: daniel@daniel.com
Has free seats: Yes

Name: Chris
E-mail: chris@chris.com
Has free seats: No

But I want Daniel has free seats to be "No"

Comment: Typo? `Car::Car(unsigned int freeSeas) : freeSeats{ freeSeats } {}` The constructor argument `freeSeas` is never used in the constructor.

Comment: `warning: field 'freeSeats' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]`, `warning: unused parameter 'freeSeas' [-Wunused-parameter]`. Turn up your compiler warnings!

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't write code like `if(condition) return true; else return false;` – just have `return condition;`, that's much cleaner code.

Comment: In an unrelated comment on your code, I'm uncomfortable with passing around `Car*` to a constructor and not deleting it in a destructor.  Options:  `const Car&` or `const Car*` for the member and parameter, smart pointers (`std::make_unique()` the Cars, with a `unique_ptr` member), `new` the `Car`s and give `Person` a destructor that deletes them.  That last one is considered "old school" these days, and not in a good way.  @Aconcagua: Surprised I missed that, its a "pet peeve" of mine.

Comment: Fixing the "typo" I believe creates a compiler error because "freeSeats" in that context could now mean either the parameter or the member variable.  You'll have to change the name of one of them (and leaving the typo in place is a bad idea... code should be clear).  While there are many opinions on whether or not to prefix member variables with something to identify them as such `m_freeSeats`, an argument in favor is that it eliminates this particular problem.

Comment: @MarkStorer It's totally fine to have a parameter and a member with same name in the constructor. The initialiser list's syntax makes obvious when the member is used (`: member(...)`, in any other location, it is hidden by the parameter (but can be referred to e. g. via `this->member`).

Comment: @Aconcagua The `member` sure, but I expected the second reference would be ambiguous.  Compiler Explorer says I'm wrong in every version of every compiler I tried though.  Live and learn.  I've been working to avoid shadowing variables for so long I forgot what the behavior was.  One of those "He's forgotten more about C++ than most will ever learn" things I guess.

Comment: Either way, you SHOULD change the variable name so there isn't a collision to avoid human confusion, even if the compiler will get it right (and it does).  A large portion of the effort that goes into coding is to make sure humans can understand it (including yourself six months later).  Some would argue "over half the effort".

Comment: I don't agree that it's necessary to change names to differ. Usually member field and constructor argument will have the same name, because they are the same and they mean the same. Forcing a rule to have different names for these two inevitably leads to Hungarian notation (either `m_field {field}` or something like `field {providedField}`).

Comment: @MarkStorer `ClassName(ArgType name) : name(name) {}` is completely normal and safe and always has been. Inventing some new, different term for the object to use only once gains you absolutely nothing and potentially causes various degrees of mayhem. (That being said, in some very rare cases I'll stick a "new" at the front of the parameter name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a typo here:

```
Car::Car(unsigned int freeSeas) :
    freeSeats{ freeSeats }
    {}
```

You wrote `freeSeas` instead of `freeSeats`. Due to that, the `freeSeas` parameter is unused and `freeSeats{ freeSeats }` does nothing as `freeSeats` is refering to the member variable, not the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Debugging is *way easier* when you enable compiler warnings. Compiler is your friend, and will help you immensely if you are willing to hear it.

For example, `gcc` gave me the following warnings when compiling your code:

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'Car::Car(unsigned int)':
prog.cc:37:23: warning: unused parameter 'freeSeas' [-Wunused-parameter]
 Car::Car(unsigned int freeSeas) :
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
prog.cc: In constructor 'Car::Car(unsigned int)':
prog.cc:38:16: warning: '*<unknown>.Car::freeSeats' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     freeSeats{ freeSeats }
                ^~~~~~~~~
```

I don't have to understand everything, but it tells me 2 things:

1. There is unused argument (why? it is used to initialize...)
2. Variable is initialized with uninitialized value (why?)

It made me look closer at this constructor and then you can see the typo.